# How to alternate case of letters in a string?

Tags: javascript

I would like to alternate cases along the string for more than one word. Every word should start with capital letter. I've got stuck in the process and don't know how sort it out.

Example: input: "hello world" / output: "HeLlO WoRlD"

```js
function alternateCase(str) {

  if (str.length === 0) {
    return ""
  }
  const arrCapitalised = []

  const splitStr = str.split("")
  const indexSpace = splitStr.indexOf(" ")

  const joinStr = str.split(" ").join("")


  for (let i = 0; i < joinStr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      arrCapitalised.push(joinStr[i].toUpperCase())
    } else {
      arrCapitalised.push(joinStr[i])
    }
  }
  console.log(arrCapitalised, "PREVIOUS ARRAY")
  const finalArr = arrCapitalised.splice(indexSpace, 0, " ")
  console.log(finalArr, "FINAL ARRAY")
  return arrCapitalised.join("").toString()
}
```

Comment: You need nested loops: The outer loop iterates over the words, the inner loop iterates over the characters in each word.

Comment: Based on your code, I assume inputs are always lowercase? Or does lowercasing uppercase letters need to be included? (I.e., forcing the case of each letter instead of only uppercasing.)

Answer (score 1):

eAsY...

```js
console.log( alternateCase4words( 'hello my world !' ));

function alternateCase4words( sentence )
  {
  const
    ope = [ (s)=>s.toUpperCase(), (s)=>s.toLowerCase() ]
  , onW = w => Array.from( w, (c,i) => ope[i&1](c) ).join('')
    ;
  return sentence.split(' ').map( word => onW(word)).join(' ');
  }
```

Some explanations... (for beginner in programming)
-1-

```
const ope = [ (s)=>s.toUpperCase(), (s)=>s.toLowerCase() ]
```

is equivalent to:

```
const ope = []
ope[0] = function(s) { return s.toUpperCase() }
ope[1] = function(s) { return s.toLowerCase() }
```

in other words:

```
ope[0]('x')  // will return 'X' UpperCase
ope[1]('Y')  // will return 'y' LowerCase
```

-2-
`i&1` -> it's Boolean algebra ->  `i AND 1`.
In  Boolean algebra `AND` is a "mask" operator.
-> So: `i & 1` allows you to recover the last bit value of `i`.
this is binary base where values could only be with composed with `0` or a `1` values,
also, all even values end with a binary zero,
odd ones end with one `1`, [you know ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

Comment: ++   I think this is the best answer because of the "some explanations".
If an answer solves your problem but you don't understand why it does it's not a great answer.  In some answers it tests the current case of the letter, but that's irrelevant — you want either an upper- or lower- case letter, and that doesn't depend on the current case of the letter, so it's pointless to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a boolean flag for the current case and reset that when you hit a space. Also note that you probably should call `.toLowerCase` when inserting a lowercase character, to make the function work correctly for non-lowercase inputs.

```js
function alternateCase(str) {
    let out = '';
    let isUpper = true;
    for(const char of str) {
        if(isUpper)
            out += char.toUpperCase();
        else
            out += char.toLowerCase();

        isUpper = char === ' ' || !isUpper;
    }
    return out;
}

console.log(alternateCase('hello world')) // HeLlO WoRlD
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is is:

I transformed the word into an array of characters, then looped once through it and used the upper case into the even letters.

```js
function alternateCase(str) {
    const words = str.split(' ');
    const result = [];
    
    words.forEach((word) => {
        Array.from(word).forEach((letter,idx) => {
            if (idx % 2 === 0) {
                result.push(letter.toUpperCase());
            } else {
                result.push(letter);
            }
        })
        result.push(' ');
    })
    return result.join('');
}

console.log(alternateCase('hello world test test test'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of a parsing function gives the most stable result imho. The snippet first converts the string to lower case, then loops all letters from it. In the loop it checks the case of the previous letter and it not being any 'non letter' and converts the current letter accordingly.

Alternatively you can use a reducer on the lowercase string converted to an array, see `alternateCaseReducer` in the snippet.

```js
const someStr = `hello world and universe`;
const anotherStr = `helLO@wOrld|@UnIverse & ETCETERA`;

console.log(alternateCase(someStr));
console.log(alternateCase(anotherStr));
console.log(alternateCaseReducer(anotherStr));

function alternateCase(someString) {
  const str = [...someString.toLowerCase()];
  let prev = str.shift().toUpperCase();
  let result = prev;
  
  while (str.length) {
    result += str.shift()[`to${
      /\p{Lu}/u.test(prev) ? `Lower` : `Upper`}Case`]();
    prev = result.at(-1);
  }
  
  return result;
}

// Alternative: reduce
function alternateCaseReducer(someString) {
  return [...someString.toLowerCase()].slice(1)
    .reduce((acc, v, i) => acc + ( !/\p{Lu}/u.test(acc.at(-1)) 
        ? v.toUpperCase() : v.toLowerCase() ), 
    someString[0].toUpperCase())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could toggle the method for changing the case and reset if a space is found.

```js
function alternateCase(string) {
    const
        toggle = { toLowerCase: 'toUpperCase', toUpperCase: 'toLowerCase' };
    let
        method = 'toUpperCase',
        result = '';
        
    for (const c of string) {
        result += c[method]();
        method = c === ' ' ? 'toUpperCase': toggle[method];
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(alternateCase('hello world'));
console.log(alternateCase('four letters'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of smart folks have weighed in with smart answers. I offer this one for its relative brevity and simplicity.

`altCapsStr` splits the string into letters, then maps with a function that sets even numbered indexes to uppercase, the others to lowercase.

Even terser and simpler, `altCaps` splits its param on blanks, and maps over those tokens with the previous function. Call this with single words or multi-word sentences.

```js
// return str with alternating caps
function altCapsStr(str) {  
  const letters = str.split('').map((c,i) => {
    return i%2 ? c.toLowerCase() : c.toUpperCase();
  });
  return letters.join('');
}

// return each blank delimited token in str with alternating  caps
function altCaps(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(altCapsStr).join(' ');
}

console.log(altCaps("word"))
console.log(altCaps("hello world"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already has a lot of working answers, but this is the way I would approach it. I feel it's straightforward and more easily understandable than the other answers:

```js
const alternateCase = (str) => {
  return str
    // Split the string into an array of words.
    .split(' ')
    // For each word...
    .map((word) => {
      return Array
        // Convert the word into an array of letters.
        .from(word)
        // For each letter...
        .map((letter, i) => {
          // Uppercase the letter if it's odd in the order, lowercase it if it's even.
          return (i % 2) ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase()
        })
        // Rejoin the letters into words.
        .join('')
    })
    // Rejoin the words into a string
    .join(' ')
}

console.log(alternateCase('hello world'))
console.log(alternateCase('one two three four five six seven'))
```

This is able to be reformatted to a one-liner (though I don't recommend it):

```
const alternateCase = (str) => str.split(" ").map(word => Array.from(word).map((letter, i) => i % 2 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase()).join("")).join(" ")
```